# Is this the correct definition of cokernel pair along with its commutative diagram from the definition of kernel pair?

Tags: category-theory, notation, definition

The following definition of Kernel Pair is taken from $\textit{Theory of Categories}$ by Nicolae Popescu and Liliana Popescu

Definition of Kernel Pair

$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} Z & \xrightarrow{u} & X\\
\small {v}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {f}  &  \\
X & \xrightarrow{f} & Y 
\end{array}$

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism.  An ordered pair $(u,v):Z\rightarrow X$ of morphisms is called a $\textit{kernel pair}$ of $f$ if $f\circ u=f\circ v$, and furthermore if for each ordered pair $(u',v'):Z'\rightarrow X$ of morphisms, such that $f\circ u'=f\circ v',$ there exists a unique morphism $g:Z'\rightarrow Z$ with $u\circ g=u'$ and $v\circ g=v'.$

Definition of Cokernel Pair

$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} Z & \xleftarrow{s} & X\\
\small {r}\big\uparrow & & \big\uparrow\small {p}  &  \\
X & \xleftarrow{p} & Y 
\end{array}$

Let $p:Y\rightarrow X$ be a morphism.  An ordered pair $(r,s):X\rightarrow Z$ of morphisms is called a $\textit{cokernel pair}$ of $p$ if $r\circ p=s\circ p$, and furthermore if for each ordered pair $(r',s'):X\rightarrow Z'$ of morphisms, such that $r'\circ p=s'\circ p,$ there exists a unique morphism $w:Z\rightarrow Z'$ with $w\circ r=r'$ and $w\circ s=s'.$

Questions:  I written out the definition of cokernel pair along with the commutative square diagram. I think it is suppose to be a pushout diagram if I reverse all the arrows in the pullback diagram for kernel pair.  I would like to know if the definition that I have written out for cokernel pair is correct.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yep, well done. Good thing to do with these general definitions is also often to check how it would look like for additive categories which then should give ordinary kernels and cokernels by replacing one of the objects by 0, which you are nicely reproducing!